# Flaws in Django-React apps

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs

I am building a Web app, powered by react in frontend and Django in the backend.

It uses Django REST framework for providing raw data to react

But when it came to data transfer, I got scared.. I was told to use CORS headers and use a WHITELIST list to mention the allowed urls which can access the data.
Also, when I need to feed an entry in database, I need to make further allowances.

So is it safe to go like this?
I think one can easily steal data midway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to set up CORS only if your React and Django apps are on different domains/ports or use different protocols.

If that's the case, whitelisting the origin of the React app in Django is the proper (only) way to go. It's not specific to Django - that's a browser feature.

Actually, I would be worried if a backend framework accepts cross-origin requests without explicit set up.

I guess your current issue comes from node and django dev servers running on different ports. If that's true and both apps will be accessible on the same domain when deployed, you can just allow all cross-origin requests when `DEBUG=True`

Read more on the topic on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: Isn't that obvious that they would run on different protocols? If it isnt, any option for merging them? Pardon me, its the first time I'm doing this django react thing

Comment: Yeah, i made that cross-origin requests to be open for feeding data into the database

Comment: I added some clarification to my answer. Normally, you'll have both apps running on different ports when you have node and django dev servers running locally. When the project is deployed, both will be served on port 443 or 80.